# Array of structures manipulation

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

I have an array of this struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    char dni[9];
    char nombre [100], apellido [100];
    double monto_adeudado;
} t_datos;
```

I need to copy the entire array into another array but with this restriction: if two or more values have the same `dni` value only output one object into the resulting array and the value of `monto_adeudado` will be the sum of all the elements with the same `dni` value. I've wrote some code but it's not working properly, it's working fine only when two values have the same `dni` value. I'm setting "0" as `dni` value for the element that I've already added.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0, x = 0, y = 0, ret = 1;
    t_datos arr[3];
    t_datos aux[3];
    char *b = "0";

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
         for(x = i + 1; x < 3; x++)
         {
             ret = strcmp(arr[i].dni, arr[x].dni);

             if(ret == 0)
             {
                 aux[y] = arr[i];
                 aux[y].monto_adeudado += arr[x].monto_adeudado;
                 *arr[x].dni = "0"; 
                 y++;
             }
         }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ret = strcmp(b, arr[i].dni);

        if (ret != 0)
        {
            aux[y] = arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm doesn't look right. If you are OK with a linear search (which will take quadratic time to run), you can use an approach like this:

```
int NUM = 3; // size of input array
int cur = 0;
for(int i=0; i<NUM; i++) {
    bool found = false;
    for(int j=0; j<cur; j++) {
        if(0 == strcmp(arr[i].dni, aux[j].dni)) {
            // found an existing entry, add to it
            aux[j].monto_adeudado += arr[i].monto_adeudado;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found) {
        // didn't find an existing entry
        aux[cur++] = arr[i];
    }
}
```

No need to futz with the existing name here - this just builds the output array element-by-element.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm setting "0" as dni value

You are not doing that as this

```
*arr[x].dni = "0";
```

is exactly this:

```
arr[x].dni[0] = address of string literal "0";
```

which is wrong of course. You need to use either `strncpy` there or

```
arr[x].dni[0] = '0'; 
arr[x].dni[1] = '\0';
```